# Python: How to get all keys in a dictionary which start with a given substring s

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I have a dictionary with names as keys and the phone numbers as values

`dictionary = {"ABCD":12345 , "EFGH":6789}`

I want to enter a substring say AB and print all keys which start with that substring

I also want to return there respective values seperately

Comment: Okay. The next step is to code your design.

Comment: This is not an access pattern dicts are optimized for - the only way to find the keys you want is a brute force search. You may want to change how you organize your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matching keys and values could be assigned to separate variables using zip on the filtered dictionary items:

```
matching    = lambda kv:kv[0].startswith("AB")
keys,values = zip(*filter(matching,dictionary.items()))
```